# What the bean scope of a confluence plugin component and how to control it?

Tags: scope, confluence, spring-bean, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I develop a confluence plugin using atlassian sdk. When using plugins-version 2, according to Atlassian docs, for every  a bean is instantiated, if the bean is public, it is also exposed as OSGI service (which i can see on the Felix console). (See [atlassian docu](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/creating-plugin-module-instances).)

I have 3 copmponents in my confluence plugin so far, one of them is public, the others are "private" (public="false"). My main bean (named "artifact-store") - the one which is public - i use in some macro classes and inject it via constructor. In `atlassian-plugin.xml` i've declared the component like this:

```
<component key="artifact-store" class="info.magnolia.sys.confluence.plugin.artifactinfo.artifactstore.ArtifactCache" name="Artifact store to cache artifacts" public="true">
 <interface>info.magnolia.sys.confluence.plugin.artifactinfo.ArtifactSearch</interface>
  <description key="artifact-store.decription">Artifact store to cache artifacts based on Atlassian cache api.</description>
</component>
```

Atlassian docu says: *"Instances are created per usage (prototype-scope) ..."* I doubt about this. When debugging my macros, i always see the same instance of "artifact-store", that's why i think the scope is NOT "prototype".
This would be fine for me, i want the scope "singleton", but i'm unsure whether it really is.
For further bean control Atlassian recommends declaring the beans in META-INF/spring/, hence i've created the spring beans "definition" `artifact-info-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/artifact-info-plugin.xml`; i have added there one bean:

```
<bean id="artifactSearchBean" class="info.magnolia.sys.confluence.plugin.artifactinfo.artifactstore.ArtifactCache" scope="singleton">
  <description>A bean chaching artifact data</description>
</bean>
```

In In `atlassian-plugin.xml` i've changed the component definition to:

```
<component key="artifact-store" class="bean:artifactSearchBean" name="Artifact store to cache artifacts" public="true">
  <interface>info.magnolia.sys.confluence.plugin.artifactinfo.ArtifactSearch</interface>
  <description key="artifact-store.decription">Artifact store to cache artifacts based on Atlassian cache api.</description>
</component>
```

I've tried it out, but doesn't work for me, there is no more bean available; none of the components are created; as a consequence, the macros (consuming component beans) also aren't available any more.

To summarize the questions:

- What's the bean scope of a confluence plugin `<component/>`?
- Is the scope the same for both public and "private" component beans?
- How can i ensure to have a singleton scoped bean?
- Is it really possible to declare the component bean in `META-INF/spring/beans.xml`? If yes, how? Could you provide an short example?

Some maybe further interesting infos about my environment:
in pom:

```
<confluence.version>5.8.9</confluence.version>
<confluence.data.version>5.8.9</confluence.data.version>
<amps.version>5.1.11</amps.version>
```

in atlassian-plugin.xml: `<atlassian-plugin plugins-version="2"/>`

Because i'm not allowed to add more then 2 links, i'll add complete links to pom file, plugin xml and beans xml as comments.

Comment: - pom: https://gist.github.com/Watcher24/247d7b633095e1a8ce59
 
 - plugin-xml: https://gist.github.com/Watcher24/62937ba288bdd2eeb552
 
 - beans-xml: https://gist.github.com/Watcher24/1e6fd0d6fdc48f4cb9d6

Answer (score 1):

> What's the bean scope of a confluence plugin ?

It's singleton

> Is the scope the same for both public and "private" component beans?

Yes

> How can i ensure to have a singleton scoped bean?

If defined in atlassian-plugin.xml they already are singleton.

> Is it really possible to declare the component bean in META-INF/spring/beans.xml? If yes, how? Could you provide an short example?

I never tried defining beans.xml. I only have spring annotation config:
Added src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/spring.xml with following content:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.jiraworkcalendar" />
</beans
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!